# Executing jar file returns nullPointerException cause can't find text file

Tags: java, jar, text-files

I am trying to access the text file within my project directory in Java language.
 That's the snippet of code:

```
buffer = new BufferedReader(new `FileReader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("English_names.txt").getPath()));`
```

Whilst you run program on Eclipse it works fine, once you print the path this

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("English_names.txt").getPath()
```

code returns it point exactly to the file.
But once I create runnable jar file the program does not start from the jar file: Missing main class or something (feedback on the screen). Once you run `java -jar jarfile.jar` command on command line it is saying that it can't find the file (returns NullPointerException)
What is the problem? Thanks

Comment: Are you packaging the .txt file inside the JAR file when you create it?

Comment: Did you try using `getResourceAsStream`?

Comment: I think it shall be included into the jar file. I make up the jar via Eclipse IDE. The files is within project's directory, as far as I can see it has been staying within bin directory too besides top directory.

Comment: @uml Do you *think* it's in the jar file, or do you *know* it's in the jar file? You can check.

Comment: Yeap, the file is not in the jar file. I have added it in, but it does not make any difference. I used WinRaR to add the file in. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am working on it right now. Trying to use BufferedInputStream encapsulating the input stream returned by that method. But for some reasons it does not go nowhere.